# Is there a 'concurrent execution' option in Azure Automate Powershell Runbooks?

Tags: azure, powershell, concurrency, azure-powershell, azure-runbook

I am working on automating maintenance tasks for a few thousand Azure SQL DBs via **Azure Automate**. I do not want to be limited to sequential execution since it will take too much time.

Is there a solution to run Azure Automate runbooks concurrently with Powershell?

Note: Creating dozens of runbooks running simultaneously is not ideal if concurrency is possible.

Comment: We can create a run time schedule and register it with the runbook to run concurrently. Did you try any other way?

Comment: Can you elaborate the concurrent part? I think it runs single-threaded by default. Is there an option to run powershell runbooks multi-threaded?

Comment: please [refer](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/52476.azure-create-runbook-and-add-schedules-using-powershell.aspx#:~:text=Azure%3A%20Create%20Runbook%20and%20add%20Schedules%20using%20PowerShell,7%20Schedule%20the%20runbook%20...%208%20Summary%20) this to work with run time schedules